# python using if and for function for dictionary with a list

Tags: python

Hi am a new to python and would like some instances for this problem i am currently facing. I recently learnt about dictionaries and list and found out that the values of the dictionary can be formatted as a list.

Problems faced:
1) why doesnt my function work if i use return v or x? It will return me the value of another key for example "zipper" in this case. I wanted to understand why it doesnt work for the values stored in a list, all values of the snack key.
I was expecting it to return me the value of sweets if i were to input "sweets" as x in the parameter.

Ie if i input sweets in the parameter as X, when the function is called it will print out the value of zipper ( i do not know why )
However if i change the return value to return (x) it solves the problem but i just wanted to understand why return V or X doesnt work

```
bagpack= {
  "pouch":"water bottle",
  "snacks":["chocolate","sweets", "icecream"],
  "front_zip":"zipper"
}

def search_bag(x):
    for k, v in bagpack.iteritems():
        for snack in bagpack["snacks"]:
            if v == x or snack == x:
                return v or x


print(search_bag("chocolate"))
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Keep in mind that we have no idea what your code is supposed to (because you haven't explained anything), so we can't tell the difference between a correct result and an incorrect result.

Comment: @Aran-Fey sorry i am not really sure how i am supposed to ask the question, it's my first time doing so. by doesnt work i mean the system will say error. what i am trying to say is if i set the return to be v or x when i input sweets for example in the parameter it doesnt print out sweets when the function is called. instead it shows me zipper for some reason

Comment: You should explain what your function is supposed to do. It helps to explicitly state your expectations; for example you could say "I expected `search_bag("chocolate")` to return X, but it returned Y instead" to make it more clear.

Comment: @YeoBryan to add to Aran-Fey's comment: if you have an exception, you should also post the _whole_ error message, including the traceback.

Comment: @Aran-Fey is it better now?  thanks for the help

Comment: @YeoBryan with the properly reformatted code I don't have any exception.

Comment: @YeoBryan but we still don't know what your function is supposed to return.

Comment: You may want to read this too : https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: It's better now, but it still sounds a bit confused. It would help if you started by explaining what the function is supposed to do _before_ you start saying things like "why doesn't it work" or "it's returning X instead of Y". A proper description of the function like "Given X as input, the function should return X if X is present as a value in the dict and Y otherwise" would go a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need to find all keys in dictionary with the item specified, you could use something like this:

```
bagpack= {
  "pouch":"water bottle",
  "snacks":["chocolate","sweets", "icecream"],
  "front_zip":"zipper"
}

def search_bag(x):
    lst = []
    for k, v in bagpack.iteritems():   # items() in python3
        if isinstance(v, list):
            v = ' '.join(v)
            if x in v:
                lst.append(k)
        else:
            if x == v:
                lst.append(k)
    return lst

print('Found in {}'.format(', '.join(search_bag("chocolate"))))
# Found in snacks
```

Comment: Thanks!! do you mind telling why when you lst.append(k), not all the keys are added into 1st variable? for example storing pouch, snacks and front_zip

Comment: `lst.append(k)` will append all keys with item specified. For example: if `chocolate` is in more than one key (in case), you need multiple keys as output. With your present strategy, you return from function immediately if you find a match.

Comment: I've edited my code. Now it checks if value is a list or not before checking the condition. So if you search for `bottle`, it does not return anything when it shouldn't. Only when you specify exactly like `water bottle`, it returns a success. (Note Aran-Frey's comment in the other answer). Glad to help you :)

Comment: Sorry but can you explain in like really layman terms for the part where what kinds of value will be appended when you use the "variable" k. For example if you use the parameter as x as sweet and it meets the condition of X in V. Will it system be able to identify which K(key) is = to that value and hence store it? Is this the way it works

Comment: In each iterations of the loop, `k` and `v` will be one key-value pair of the dictionary. Yeah, if `x` is `sweets`, then corresponding key `k` (`snacks`) will be appended to `lst`. It does not stop there. It looks for each key-value pairs in each iterations, check if `x` is in value, if so append the corresponding key `k` to `lst`. Did you get it now?

Comment: omg thanks i got it now. Would it be the same if rather than to append the K, you print it instead? So instead of printing all the keys of K it just prints the K that corresponds to X that meets the criteria. Seriously thanks!Time for me to learn more of the functions so i know how the instance segment works

Comment: Ofcourse, you could print there itself without appending to a list - there are many ways of doing things. Regarding `isintance`, it is like type-checking you see in most other languages. You need to learn more on that. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

updated your search function in the following way:

```
def search_bag(x):
  for k, v in bagpack.iteritems():
      if x in v:
          return k
```

Basically, search for the String in object or array and return the key.
Assumption: x being sent in present inexact in the values soemwhere

Comment: sorry if i was unclear but i am actually not looking for the key, i just wanted to that particular value to be printed out if it matches the parameter. The functions work if i just type return X but i wanted to know why return v or x doesnt work

Comment: Your function doesn't account for whether the value is a list or a string. If you call `search_bag('bottle')`, your function will check `if 'bottle' in 'water bottle':` and will return the corresponding key.

Comment: @Aran-Fey i assume the input would be provided exactly.

Comment: Considering that this is a function that _searches_ for items in the bag, I don't think that's a good assumption to make. You should probably state such assumptions in the answer, because they really aren't obvious.

Comment: @YeoBryan `return v or x` works but your logic is slightly flawed. You can put down print statements to see that. The function fails if` x = 'chocolate'` as `["chocolate","sweets", "icecream"] == 'chocolate'` is false.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas but having listed the elements separately via the for function, for snack in bagpack["snacks"]:, shouldnt it be checking " chocolate" against "chocolate", "sweets" , "icecream" ?

Comment: @YeoBryan Yes it should but the code doesn't reach that key. The first key, value being returned in iteritems loop is **front_zip,zipper** and then the inner loop runs. The first condition is always false but the second condition gets satisfied in the second time of the for loop and returns zipper in your code. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want true or false as an outcome

```
bagpack= {
    "pouch":"water bottle",
    "snacks":["chocolate","sweets", "icecream"],
    "front_zip":"zipper"
}

def search_bag(x):
    for k, v in bagpack.iteritems():
        for snack in bagpack["snacks"]:
            if v == x or snack == x:
                return v == x or snack == x
        return False

print("search Result : " + str(search_bag("chocolate")))
```

**outcome**
search Result : True

Answer (score 0):

The very first and simplest solution to debug a small piece of code like this is to `print()` values at a few points within the function to find out what really goes on:

```
>>> def search_bag(x):
...     for k, v in bagpack.iteritems():
...         for snack in bagpack["snacks"]:
...             print("x : '{}' - v : '{}' - snack : '{}'".format(x, v, snack))
...             if v == x or snack == x:
...                 print("'{}' or '{}' == '{}'".format(v, x, v or x))
...                 return v or x
>>> search_bag("chocolate")
x : 'chocolate' - v : 'zipper' - snack : 'chocolate'
'zipper' or 'chocolate' == 'zipper'
'zipper'
```

As you can here, your first obvious problem is that you misunderstand what the logical `or` operator does. `a or b` will first test the truth value of `a` (the result of `bool(a)`). If it's True then it returns `a` and stop here. Else, it returns `b`.

The `v == x or snack =x` expression will eval to True if either `v` or `snack` matches `x`, and to False if none of them matches `x`.

Then you return `v or x`. Since in Python a non-empty string has a `True` boolan value, the expression `"zipper" or "chocolate"` evals to `"zipper"`. Actually since you don't have any false (empty string, empty list or dict, numerical zero) value in your dict the expression `v or x` will *always* return `v`, period.

Which of `v` or `snack` actually matched `x` has *absolutely no impact* on the result of the `v or x` expression - at this point, the interpreted doesn't even know which of `v` or `snack` matched `x`, all it does is select the first of `v` and `x` that is not "false" and return it.

If you want to know which of `v` or `snack` matched and return the appropriate value, you have to do two distinct tests:

```
if v == x:
    return v # or you could return `v` as well
elif snack == x:
    return x # or you could return `snack` as well ;)
```

Now your second error is to mix different types of values (strings and lists) in your dict without *correctly* handling those different types in your `search_bag` function. Having two nested for loops, the inner one being constant (it will iterate of the same values again and again for each turn of the outer loop) is totally inefficient, and hardcoding the "snacks" key is brittle at best.

You have two possible solutions here: either make all your values lists or - instead of hardcoding some key - test the value's type and handle it accordingly:

Solution 1:

```
bagpack= {
  "pouch": ["water bottle"],
  "snacks":["chocolate","sweets", "icecream"],
  "front_zip": ["zipper"],
}
def search_bag(x):
    # if you don't need the keys then don't use them
    for values in bagpack.values():
        for v in values:
            if v == x:
                return v
```

which can be simplified using containment test:

```
def search_bag(x):
    for values in bagpack.values():
        if x in values:
            return x
```

solution 2:

```
bagpack= {
  "pouch": "water bottle",
  "snacks":["chocolate","sweets", "icecream"],
  "front_zip": "zipper",
}
def search_bag(x):
    for value in bagpack.values():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            if x in value:
                return x 
        elif x == value
            return x
```

And since all your function does is "return the searched value if it's anywhere in the dict, else returns None" - IOW it's semantic is mainly "do we have 'x' in the bag", the proper API would be to name you function "is_in_bag(x)" and make it return a boolean:

solution 1 (bagpack contains only lists):

```
def is_in_bag(x):
    return any(x in v for v in bagpack.values())
```

solution 2 (bagpack contains mixed values):

```
def is_in_bag(x):
    return any(
        x in v if isinstance(v, list) else x == v
        for v in bagpack.values()
        )
```

Comment: Much thanks for the in-depth reply but i am not really able to catch everything that you are saying especially some of the terms that you use because i am still very new to this in general.  For the code that i have written, if x = v, or snack =x.  Return k or X. If i assign the value "icecream" to X it should have failed the X = V check but pass the snack =X check right? So following that shouldnt it return me the value of  X  since none of the X = V?

Comment: Which of the tests in the `if` statement evaled to True is totally irrelevant and has absolutely no impact on the result of the `return v or x` statement. The value of the `v or x` expression depends solely on `x` and `v` values, and will always be the same for the same values of `v` and `x`.